# Союз или вводное слово?

Tags: пунктуация, морфология

"Это не совсем ужасно, скорее неприятно".
Является ли в предложении выше "не совсем скорее" составным союзом (наподобие "не только но и") и правильно ли поставлена запятая?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуем представить грамматический анализ следующим образом.

"Это не совсем ужасно, скорее неприятно". Это предложение с БЕССОЮЗНОЙ связью сказуемых, ставится запятая. СЕМАНТИЧЕСКИ сказуемые связаны отношением сопоставления, для выражения которого используются частицы НЕ СОВСЕМ и  наречие  СКОРЕЕ.

Это же сообщение можно выразить следующим образом: "Это не совсем ужасно, а, скорее, неприятно". Это уже союзная связь: А - противительный союз, СКОРЕЕ - вводное слово.

Answer (score 0):

Бессоюзная связь, запятая нужна.

Answer (score 0):

В Справочнике по пунктуации на Грамота.ру (http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_671) сказано:

"Слово «скорее» не требует постановки знаков препинания, если в предложении подразумевается сопоставление «скорее… чем», «скорее… нежели».

*Посетители походили скорее на бизнесменов. Всё это напоминало скорее глупую комедию.* (Ср.: *Посетители походили скорее на бизнесменов, чем на любопытных зевак; Всё это напоминало скорее глупую комедию, нежели реальное происшествие*)".

В данном случае "скорее" рассматривается как союз, вернее, как часть подразумеваемого союза "скорее... чем".

*Это не совсем ужасно, скорее неприятно* = *Это скорее неприятно, чем ужасно*.

Запятая после "скорее" не нужна, так как это не вводное слово.

Comment: Мне нравится Справочник по пунктуации на Грамота.ру . Там  как в сказке, там всё возможно: союзы, как виртуальные частицы, рождаются, исчезают, подразумеваются, разделяются на части и соединяются вновь. Кроме того, они рассматриваются, изучаются и всегда бывают не вообще, а в данном случае.

Comment: Но значение наречия-то в данном случае не подходит.

Comment: Имеется конструкция: Это не А, (а) скорее Б (ПРОТИВОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕ). Как сделать из нее СОПОСТАВЛЕНИЕ? Нет ничего проще. Прежде всего, надо избавиться от частицы НЕ, она здесь лишняя. Затем заменим ее на союз ЧЕМ, который будет подразумеваться. Получаем: Это чем А, скорее Б. Теперь можно и знаки препинания расставить. Примечание. Это всё шутка (смайлик).

Answer (score 0):

> Является ли в предложении выше "не совсем скорее" составным союзом (наподобие "не только но и") и правильно ли поставлена запятая?

Нет. Для признания конструкции составным союзом необходимо, чтобы удаление хотя бы одной из присоединяемых частей приводило бы к грамматической некорректности. В нашем случае возможно и "Это не совсем ужасно" "Это скорее неприятно". 
Таким образом запятая нужна, как уже сказали выше.